# Speed limit does not work, but snap to roads and the other features does

Tags: google-roads-api

When I access this link : `https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=38.75807927603043,-9.03741754643809|38.6896537,-9.1770515|41.1399289,-8.6094075&key=YOUR_API_KEY` for google ROADS API it gives me the following error :

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Speed limits are not available for this project.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I need to mention that the other links work (for snap to roads, nearest roads). Only this one throws and error. I made sure to enable the ROADS API in the dashboard and I checked the documentation where they talked about the reason for getting this type of error (and none of their fixes helped so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the note at the top of the documentation page:

> Notice: The Speed Limit service is **available to all customers with an Asset Tracking license**. For Google Maps Platform Premium Plan customers who transitioned to pay-as-you-go pricing, the Speed Limit feature remains active on projects with Asset Tracking capabilities (projects with a project ID in the format maps-asset-xxx).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits